# Is there a way to shorten defining v-model data, Vue.js and Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

On my edit page of CRUD project, I have a code that fills the form with values of which record is being edited.
 I use `v-model` to define HTML inputs, but the code seems too long.

I get the data from the prop, and fill the `v-model`.

**My code that fills v-model**

```
created() {
            this.studentData = this.student;
            this.first_name = this.student.first_name;
            this.last_name = this.student.last_name;
            this.student_number = this.student.last_name;
            this.phone_number = this.student.phone_number;
            this.email = this.student.email;
            this.birth_date = moment(this.student.birth_date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
            this.school_name = this.student.school_name;
        }
```

**The way I get the data using prop:** `props: ['student']` and in blade `<student-edit-component :student="{{$student}}">`

**Defining v-models in script**

```
data () {
            return {
                first_name: '',
                last_name: '',
                student_number: '',
                phone_number: '',
                email: '',
                birth_date: '',
                school_name: '',
            };
        },
```

That fills the value on the form inputs with it's data.

Is there a way to shorten this code using props or arrays?

Please help me, I'm so new to Vue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your model of data adding a new layer. For example:

```
  data() {
    return {
      currentStudent: {
        first_name: '',
        last_name: '',
        student_number: '',
        phone_number: '',
        email: '',
        birth_date: '',
        school_name: '',
      }
    }
  },
```

Then in `created` you can use simple

```
  created() {
    this.currentStudent = this.student;
    this.currentStudent.birth_date = moment(this.student.birth_date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  },
```

And in all component replace names  by names with `currentStudne` eg in `v-models`:

```
first_name -> currentStudne.first_name
```

You can also read about `Vue.$set`

> https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Comment: Hello Daniel, can I ask you something looks like this problem?

Comment: You have answers for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63908277/putting-data-inside-prop-to-make-it-look-tidy-vue-js but I added my comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the object `studentData`, it is working well with `v-model`.
First, you pass the props like that :

`<student-edit-component :student="student">` (no need to use the `${{}}`).

Then in the component `StudentEditComponent', you can use :

```
props: {
    student: {
        type: Object,
        required: true,
        default : () => {},
    }
}
```

You should use the type, required and default properties, it is a good practice.
Then

```
data () {
        return {
            studentForm: {},
        };
    },

created() {
        this.studentForm = this.student;
    }
```

In the template, you can after that use `v-model="studentForm.first_name"`