# Putting data inside prop to make it look tidy Vue.js

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a create page, I make a POST request using Axios and it works great. But I think my code is not healthy at all.

**That is how I define my props:**

```
data () {
            return {

                first_name: '',
                last_name: '',
                student_number: '',
                phone_number: '',
                email: '',
                birth_date: '',
                school_name: '',
            };
        },
```

These things are `v-model`'s objects. I use them to make a POST request to my API. But instead of writing them one by one, can I put these in an array or a prop?

When I'm making a request to API, I define my `v-model`'s one by one again.

**Like this**

```
axios.post(`/api/students`, {

                first_name:this.first_name,
                last_name:this.last_name,
                student_number:this.student_number,
                phone_number:this.phone_number,
                email:this.email,
                birth_date:this.birth_date,
                school_name:this.school_name,
```

Can I send them in just one or two line?

Like: `postedData:this.studentData;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the previous answer is correct for this particular use-case, if you were to add properties that you don't want to send, it wouldn't work anymore. A better approach is to put all those properties inside an object, let's name it `studentData`, like this:

```js
data() {
  return {
    studentData: {
      first_name: '',
      last_name: '',
      student_number: '',
      phone_number: '',
      email: '',
      birth_date: '',
      school_name: '',
    },
  };
}
```

and then you can do

```js
axios.post('/api/students', this.studentData);
```

Note that you'll also need to update your `v-model`s like `v-model="studentData.first_name"` instead of `v-model="first_name"`.

Comment: It is the same approach as presented in question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63905717/is-there-a-way-to-shorten-defining-v-model-data-vue-js-and-laravel I strongly recommend this solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can access component props or data from `this.$props` or `this.$data`,

So you can simply do

```js
axios.post(`/api/students`, this.$data);
```

But this means that your are sending the entire component data on the request, to avoid this, try @BogdanL answer which is recommended.

Comment: In this particular case, this solution works, but it is a very dangerous project pattern.

Let's imagine what will happens when someone will extend data adding for example loading state or other not connected with student information.

In this case, code is short but badly designed.